# Zend - How to include file in view like masterpae asp.net?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, zend-framework, master-pages

I have structure folder like this:

http://nx9.upanh.com/b4.s37.d4/3fd103509d1ac25ece02096b5e25a5f0_55810779.capture.png

(I really sorry, I'm not enough reputation)

I want to include 2 files are header.phtml and footer.phtml from public/shared/ folder to view of default module, I use code below:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('public/shared/header.phtml'); ?>

<h3>This is index.phtml</h3>

<?php echo $this->partial('public/shared/footer.phtml'); ?>
```

But I get an error **HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)**. If I'm only using html code, there is no problem happen.

```
<h3>This is index.phtml</h3>
```

I can do like this in CodeIgniter Framework but I don't know how to do this in Zend Framework. Please help me! Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ZF1 or 2 ? In ZF1, you will want to place the header and footer into the layout.phtml file located in application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml.

The actual header.phtml and footer.phtml should be placed into the application/view/scripts folder, then you can do something like:

LAYOUT.PHTML:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('header.phtml') ?>

// this bit will render the action content
<?php print $this->layout()->content ?>

<?php echo $this->partial('footer.phtml') ?>
```

Comment: But, where I can call layout.phtml?

Comment: You don't need to call the layout.phtml. The bootstrap should manage that. Why dont you read through a tutorial or two ? see http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/